# Knockoutjs: How to bindings to html bind recursively

Tags: javascript, html, binding, knockout.js

I want to add html content dynamically using html binding, and inside that html content I have other ko bindings to be applied. however the following code doesn't work as expected:

```
<div data-bind="html: html"></div>​
<script type="text/javascript">
var vm = new function(){
    this.html = ko.observable("hello <span data-bind='text: text'></span>");
    this.text = "world";
};
ko.applyBindings(vm);
</script>
```

jsfiddle is available: http://jsfiddle.net/jvVeQ/

thanks,
Green

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/jvVeQ/1/ , I am not putting this an answer because I am not sure if this 'recursive' binding will not cause memory leaks. By the way, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am creating an online form designer. The design time html of each control is injected dynamically using html binding. In side that part I would like to continue use ko to manage the state changes. BTW, thanks for the answer!

Comment: maybe you could have the controls as templates on the html file, and then use a the template binding to choose which to render (e.g. data-bind="template: fieldType")

Comment: something like http://jsfiddle.net/guigouz/kEWK6/

Comment: guigouz and Artem, you should post these as answers.

Answer (score 0):

this can be done through knockout templates.

Have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MaurizioPiccini/QfLxM/13/):

In your case it will be something like this:

```
<div data-bind="template: 'myTemplate' "></div>​

<script id="myTemplate" type="text/html">
    <span data-bind='text: text'></span>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following custom Knockout binding, which is the same as the built-in `html` binding except that `controlsDescendantBindings` is `false` instead of `true`:

```
ko.bindingHandlers['htmlRecurse'] = {
    'init': function() {
        return { 'controlsDescendantBindings': false };
    },
    'update': function (element, valueAccessor) {
        ko.utils.setHtml(element, valueAccessor());
    }
};
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jvVeQ/16/

**Caution:** To avoid cross-site scripting attacks, do not construct recursive bindings from user input.